# Custom toolpanel rendered outside of grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

> **EDIT:** **thanks for the answers below. I haven't been able to solve it, but I have found the culprit in my project.**  Seems that the
> issue appears when putting the grid inside a material tab list that
> is generated with `*ngFor`  [I created an example where it goes
> wrong](https://plnkr.co/edit/JRCU3Pj04OXjSIgF)

I am using AG Grid v25 together with angular 11. When trying to build a custom toolpanel, the content always renders outside of the grid (below the grid). Even if I just put a plain `<div>test</div>` as toolpanel html content. The toolpanel button is shown and working, but opens up a blank panel while the content is rendered below the grid. Also, the content is always visible, whether the custom toolpanel with the blank content is opened or not.

I am getting no errors or warnings. I have been trying to compare with the default filter toolpanel code posted on github, but I'm at a loss. Is there anything I'm missing?

Registering my panel in the component (I also registered the panel in the module as the docs state):

```
this.frameworkComponents = {
            userSettingsToolPanel: UserSettingsToolPanel
    };
```

The sidebar code:

```
this.sideBar = {
    toolPanels: [
      {
        id: "columns",
        labelDefault: "Columns",
        labelKey: "columns",
        iconKey: "columns",
        toolPanel: "agColumnsToolPanel"
      },
      {
        id: "filters",
        labelDefault: "Filters",
        labelKey: "filters",
        iconKey: "filter",
        toolPanel: "agFiltersToolPanel"
      },
      {
          id: 'userSettingsToolPanel',
          labelDefault: 'Settings',
          labelKey: 'userSettingsToolPanel',
          iconKey: 'menu',
          toolPanel: 'userSettingsToolPanel',
        }
    ],
    hiddenByDefault: false,
    defaultToolPanel: null
  };
```

The toolpanel code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewChildren, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IToolPanel, IToolPanelParams } from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';

@Component({
  selector: 'usersettings-panel',
  template: ` <div>test</div>`,
  styles: [``]
}

)
export class UserSettingsToolPanel implements IToolPanel {

  refresh(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  private params: IToolPanelParams;

  agInit(params: IToolPanelParams): void {
    this.params = params;


  }

}
```

Comment: your custom tool panel looks fine to me, see [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/F3xNmHdNqnFC6St4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try setting the popupParent?
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/context-menu/#popup-parent

```
popupParent: Element;

constructor() {
    this.popupParent = document.querySelector('body');
  }
```

```
<ag-grid-angular [popupParent]="popupParent">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to help. I have edited my original post to add where it appears to go wrong.

Comment: As you say, it's definitely the *ngFor.  Can you try this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/T7JD7hylMsxMfjMd?preview

Move the contents of the grid to a separate component

Comment: That seems to be the solution indeed, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where a custom tool panel was rendering correctly in normal pages, but rendering outside the grid when the grid was inside a `<p-dialog>` (PrimeNG, lightbox dialog component).

I managed to solve by wrapping the `<ag-grid-angular...>` tag with just a `<div>...</div>`.

I think it's maybe a bug when the grid is transposed as a child content within another component.